# Git: Creating a fork and merging files easily

Tags: windows, git

I want to be able to create a fork of glfw (located at git@github.com:glfw/glfw.git), and with the fork I want to merge the following files to it: `glfw3.h`, `input.c`, `internal.h` and `win32_window.c`.

How can I do this properly, and ensure that only the four files I modified are pushed to my fork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `glfw` is on github,

1. Click the fork button.
2. Clone from your fork `git clone git@github.com:edition/glfw.git`
3. Add your files and commit them.
4. Push back to your fork.